# samba shares unavailable to one machine - not others?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, samba

I have 3 samba servers and a user who is having connection issues. He can see two of them but not the third. His cube-neighbor can see all three (as can the rest of us).

To further complicate matters the samba servers are EMC (works), Debian(works) and RHEL 5 (doesn't work).

He can ping the problem machine but can't browse the shares or connect to any of them.

Is this likely a

- firewall issue on his machine
- config issue on the one problem server
- other?

All user machines are running Win7 (x64) Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

On the problem machine, open the [Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon) and remove anything associated with the unavailable samba server.

Comment: Nothing entered there for problematic machine.